# Sorting Pandas data by hour of the day

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

Given the following dataset that I have extracted from an Excel file via Panda:

[image]
…

```
[131124 rows x 2 columns]

date               datetime64[ns]
places_occupees             int64
dtype: object
```

Is there a way to sort this data by the hour of day no matter the date?

What I would like to do is to get all the data in between 9 and 10 o'clock in the morning for instance.

You can find a sample of the dataset below.

https://ufile.io/jlilr

Comment: Can you give the dataframe in a format where I don't have to type it in by hand, please?

Comment: date               datetime64[ns]
places_occupees             int64
dtype: object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after converting to datetime `pd.to_datetime(df['date'])` you can create a separate column with the hour in it, e.g. `df['Hour'] = df.date.dt.hour` and then sort by it
`df.sort_values('Hour')`

## EDIT:

As you want to sort by time you can instead of using hour, put the timestamp part into a 'time' column. In order to get times between 9 and 10 you can filter by where hour==9 and then sort by the time column as per below

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

#put the timestamp part of the datetime into a separate column
df['time'] = df['date'].dt.time

#filter by times between 9 and 10 and sort by timestamp
df.loc[df.date.dt.hour==9].sort_values('time')
```

Comment: I get an error with the line df['Hour'] = df.date.dt.hour it says ttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values and this Strange is the type is Name: date, Length: 131124, dtype: datetime64[ns]

Comment: that's strange, can you try below
`df['hour'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.hour`

Comment: I no longer get an error message but now how can I sort data let's say between 09:00:00 and 10:00:00?

Comment: Please see my edited answer, if this answers your question please upvote and mark the answer as accepted

Comment: Amazing it works this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks so much for your time.

Comment: Pureluck when I try to plot the sorting result I get an error message saying "AttributeError: 'datetime.time' object has no attribute 'toordinal'" it is because of the time column we Added? So after sorting how I can I remove that column so that I can use the result as series?

Comment: you can remove columns in multiple ways, the most straight forward is likely `del df['time']`